# Beginner wanting to build a map for offline use (MyMaps, OSM or QGis?)

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, google-maps, carto, google-maps-engine

I recently managed to get GPS coordinates from a polyline embedded on a Google map I found. I would like to build my own offline map for travel purposes. I'm looking at OSM or QGis, even though I'm completely new to those apps. Like many amateurs, I've been solely using Google My Maps to plot routes around different points of interest.

So this is also advice topic as much as it's a question.

I now have GPS coordinates in txt format and I would like to use them to plot the path on the map. If any pros here can help me, what would be the most efficient solution for someone of my skill level in mapping (utter newb).

- convert the GPS coordinates to KMZ if possible, load in Google My Maps?
- import in QGis to get points and convert them to a single line
- same as above only in Open Street Maps (with CartoDB I guess? I might be wrong).

Please be patient for a newb, school me in the right direction so I don't spend hours digging thru various solutions in this overwhelming topic.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q& A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.